# New comment is creating new conversation instead of repeating the conversation

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The following code is fetching messages (status) with its comments from MySQL database from tables CHART and COMMENTS. The problem with the code first when you comment, the comment is appearing under the message (this is okay, all comments has to be under the message commented sorted from oldest to newest).

But when you comment again, it is creating a new conversation the **message and the new comment** instead of adding the comment under the first comment you send. Can someone help me to solve this? or what is the better way to do this?

```
           <?php
           $profile= htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
           $reply_acc= htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
           $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ch.msg , ch.msg_id , co.comment , co.comment_id FROM chart AS ch, comments AS co WHERE ch.msg_id=co.comment_id");
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {
           echo("
           <table border='1' width='600px'>
           <tr>
           <td>
           $row[msg]
           </td>
           </tr>

           <tr>
           <td>
           $row[comment]
           <p></p>
           <form action='drop_comment.php' method='post'>
           <input type='text' name='comment' placeholder='drop a comment...' value='' class='add_hook'>
           <input name='comment_id' type='hidden'  value='$row[msg_id]'>
           <input name='id' type='hidden'  value='$row[msg_id]'>
           <input name='comment_via' type='hidden'  value='$device'>
           <input name='comment_time' type='hidden'  value='$status_time'>
           </form>
           </td>
           </tr>
           </table>
           <p></p>
           ");
           }
           ?>
```

Comment: Add an ORDER BY clause to your query to get them in the order you want.

Comment: is just ordering the conversation not sorting the message in one table with its comments SELECT ch.msg , ch.msg_id , co.comment , co.comment_id FROM chart AS ch, comments AS co WHERE ch.msg_id=co.comment_id ORDER BY co.comment ASC

Answer (score 0):

Order the query by message and then comment. Then only print the message when it changes to group them.

```
       $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ch.msg , ch.msg_id , co.comment , co.comment_id
                                     FROM chart AS ch
                                     JOIN comments AS co
                                     ON ch.msg_id=co.comment_id
                                     ORDER BY ch.msg_id, co.comment_id");

       $last_msg = null;
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {
       if ($row['msg_id'] !== $last_msg) {
         if ($last_msg !== null) {
           echo "</table>\n<p><p>\n";
         }
         echo "<table border='1' width='600px'>
               <tr>
               <td>
               $row[msg]
               </td>
               </tr>\n";
         $last_msg = $row['msg_id'];
       }
       echo "
       <tr>
       <td>
       $row[comment]
       <p></p>
       <form action='drop_comment.php' method='post'>
       <input type='text' name='comment' placeholder='drop a comment...' value='' class='add_hook'>
       <input name='comment_id' type='hidden'  value='$row[msg_id]'>
       <input name='id' type='hidden'  value='$row[msg_id]'>
       <input name='comment_via' type='hidden'  value='$device'>
       <input name='comment_time' type='hidden'  value='$status_time'>
       </form>
       </td>
       </tr>
       ");
       }
       echo "</table>\n<p><p>\n";
```

Comment: am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\wamp\www\profile.php on line 118 how to solve this

Comment: I just corrected a `(` to `{`. You couldn't figure that out yourself by looking at the code around line 118?

Comment: is giving me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\profile.php on line 158 end 158 is the last line on my html page </html>

Comment: Just added the missing `}` to close the `while` loop.

Comment: that has worked but the posted message is failing to return because  ch.msg_id=co.comment_id when i directly create a comment in the database am able to return the message with the comment but when i commented again the new comment is appearing outside the  html table i believe the problem now is with the MYQSL tables

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you put `$row[msg_id]` in the hidden input named `comment_id`? Should that be `$row[comment_id]`?

Comment: in short what am trying to do. fist i have a text field where you will write message for others to comment, when the message has been sent we have now to see the message with comment field (like how facebook does new status which has not be commented STATUS with COMMENT FIELD when you comment it shows STATUS, COMMENT & COMMENT FIELD) thats what am looking for sir

Comment: Sounds like you should start a new question, where you post `drop_comment.php` and ask for help with it.